# problem in switching between tabs in a js to do list program

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

```js
let Id = 1;
let ToDo = [];
let IDEDIT = false;
let $ =document;

function AddToDo(edit = IDEDIT) {

  let input = $.getElementById("NewToDo");
  let list = $.getElementById("ToDoList");

  if (!edit) {

    ToDo.push({
      id: Id,
      text: input.value,
      done: 2,
    });

    list.innerHTML =list.innerHTML + " " + `<div id="item${Id}" class="item flex justify-between border rounded-lg my-5 p-5"><h3 id='${Id}titr' class="text-gray-600 font-bold "> ${input.value} </h3><div class="icon-controller flex items-center  gap-1.5 text-xl"><input value="2" onchange="ToggleDone('${Id}' )" id='${Id}Input' type="checkbox" name="" id=""><ion-icon onclick="{edit(${Id})}" class="text-[#F3C30E]" name="brush"></ion-icon><ion-icon onclick="del(${Id})" class="text-red-500" name="trash"></ion-icon> </div> </div>`;
    input.value = "";
    Id++;

  } else {

    ToDo.filter((i) => i.id == IDEDIT)[0].text =input.value;
    $.getElementById(`${IDEDIT}titr`).innerText = input.value;
    input.value = "";
    ToggleButton();
    IDEDIT =false;

  }
}

function ToggleDone(ID) {

  // "2" == false & "1" == true

  let titrEl =$.getElementById(`${ID}titr`);
  let input= $.getElementById(`${ID}Input`);
  let flag = input.value; // value of ToDo 1 or 2

  const backValue = () =>{

    return flag == 1 ? 2 : 1;

  }


  input.value = backValue() ;
  input.setAttribute("checked", flag == 1 ? false : true);
  titrEl.classList.toggle("done");
  ToDo.filter((i) => i.id == ID)[0].done = backValue();



}


function edit(ID) {

  IDEDIT = ID;
  
  let Input = $.getElementById("NewToDo");
  
  Input.value = ToDo.filter((i) => i.id == ID)[0].text;
  
  ToggleButton();

}

function del(ID) {

ToDo= ToDo.filter(i => i.id !== ID);
$.getElementById(`item${ID}`).remove();
  
}

function ToggleButton(){

  $.getElementById("create").classList.toggle("hidden");
  $.getElementById("edit").classList.toggle("hidden");

}

function filter(ID){

  
  let list = $.getElementById("ToDoList");

    // del active btn
  $.querySelectorAll(".btn-controller .active_btn").length !== 0 && $.querySelector(".btn-controller button.active_btn").classList.remove("active_btn");

  // set style
  $.getElementById(ID).classList.add("active_btn");

  // del list inner html


  const setString = (i) => {
return  `<div id="item${i.Id}" class="item flex justify-between border rounded-lg my-5 p-5"><h3 id='${i.Id}titr' class="text-gray-600 font-bold ${i.done == 1 && 'done'} "> ${i.text} </h3><div class="icon-controller flex items-center  gap-1.5 text-xl"><input value='${i.done}' ${i.done == 1 && 'checked'} onchange='ToggleDone(${i.Id})' id='${i.Id}Input' type="checkbox" name="" id=""><ion-icon onclick="{edit(${i.Id})}" class="text-[#F3C30E]" name="brush"></ion-icon><ion-icon onclick="del(${i.Id})" class="text-red-500" name="trash"></ion-icon> </div> </div>`;
  }


  
 list.innerHTML ="";

  if (ID == "all"){

 for(let i = 0; i<ToDo.length; i++){

    list.innerHTML =list.innerHTML + " " + setString(ToDo[i]);
      
    };
  } ;

    if (ID == "done") {
      let DoneList = ToDo.filter(i => i.done == 1);
      for(let i = 0; i<DoneList.length; i++){
        list.innerHTML =list.innerHTML + " " + setString(DoneList[i]);
        };


    };

     if (ID == "task") {
      let taskList = ToDo.filter(i => i.done != 1);

      for(let i = 0; i<taskList.length; i++){

      list.innerHTML =list.innerHTML + " " + setString(taskList[i]);
    
      };

    }


  };
```

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


@layer components{
    .btn{
        @apply bg-[#50A3B8] text-white rounded-md p-3 border border-white hover:bg-white hover:text-[#50A3B8] hover:border hover:border-[#50A3B8];
    }
    .active_btn{
        @apply bg-white text-[#50A3B8] border border-[#50A3B8] ;

    }
    .titr{
        @apply text-[#272B30] text-4xl text-center font-bold;
    }
    .controller-input{
        @apply flex items-center w-full;
    }
    .controller-input i{
        @apply rounded-l-md h-10 flex items-center justify-center w-[7%] bg-[#50A3B8];
    }
    .controller-input i ion-icon{
        @apply  text-white  text-2xl font-bold ;
    }
    .controller-input input{
        @apply border h-10 w-[93%] rounded-r-lg p-3;
    }
    .btn-controller button{
        @apply w-[30%]
    }
    .done{
        @apply line-through decoration-1  decoration-red-500;
        color: rgb(239 68 68 / var(--tw-text-opacity)) !important;
    }
}

        @layer base {
            .container {
              @apply com:max-w-[85%] mx-auto;
            }
    }

    .bg_yellow{
        background-color: #F3C30E !important;
    }
    .bg_yellow:hover{
        border-color:#F3C30E !important ;
        color: #F3C30E;
        background-color: white !important;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>To Do List</title>
    <link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./input.css" />
    <script
      type="module"
      src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      nomodule
      src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="main p-5 mt-10 container">
      <h2 class="titr">ToDoInput</h2>

      <div class="new-to-do flex flex-col gap-4 my-5 border-2 p-5 rounded-lg">
        <div class="controller-input">
          <i> <ion-icon name="create-outline"></ion-icon></i>

          <input id="NewToDo" type="text" placeholder="New To Do" />
        </div>
        <button id="create" onclick="AddToDo()" class="btn w-full">
          Add New Task
        </button>
        <button id="edit" onclick="AddToDo(1)" class="btn w-full bg_yellow hidden">Edit Task</button>
      </div>
      

      <div class="w-full">
        <h2 class="titr my-5">ToDoList</h2>

        <div class="btn-controller flex items-center justify-between">
          <button onclick="filter('all')" id="all" class="btn active_btn">All</button>
          <button onclick="filter('done')" id="done" class="btn">Done</button>
          <button onclick="filter('task')" id="task" class="btn">ToDo</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="ToDoList" class="item-controller text-lg mt-16"></div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I switch between filter tabs, the completed operation returns to the first state, for example, when I remove a mission from the completed state in the completed tab, when I move the tab, it returns to the first state.
Or when I complete an operation later, it does not transfer from the operations tab to the performed tab

i can't think of doing anything

Comment: No one will be able to help you without some code, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the filter function you shouldn't modify the html content. you'd want to update the data that's already stored. Should work fine after that